# Animation, FPS, and KineticJS

Tags: javascript, animation, kineticjs, frame-rate, requestanimationframe

So I have a little game of a ball moving around on the screen and I would like to calculate the FPS. I am using KineticJS (4.3.1) which utilizes requestAnimationFrame under the hood.

```
      var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(
          function(frame) {

            //game logic
               //move ball
               //check collisions - if collision occurs, stop animation
               //redraw 

          }
      }
```

The 'frame' object has a time property which can be accessed with frame.time which measures the time since the animation was first started in milliseconds.

```
     var timeSinceAnimationStarted = frame.time;
```

What would be an accurate way of measuring the FPS?

Comment: Also, this animation might go on forever, doesn't really stop unless a collision is detected.

Comment: The obvious answer would be frames_displayed / seconds_of_measurement... why are you not using that? Set a timer. Increment a counter every time you show a frame. When timer rings, see how much time has passed and how many frames were rendered.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, but basically because I haven't done this before and needed some guidance on where to put the variables. But from what you said, the structure would be to create a variable which is incremented by the animation (call it numFrames), and a timer which reads the value every second. Correct?

Comment: No need for the timer, actually - see my answer below.

Comment: The frame object has a framerate property in the recent versions of kinetic: `frame.frameRate`

Comment: yeah, I saw that, its pretty nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple implementation, with "frames in a 1s interval". You can smoothen it out using, say, frames in a 5s interval

```
// variables accessible from within function(frame)
var frameCount = 0;
var currentSecond = 0;
var frameRate = 0;

// within function(frame), called with current time on each new frame
function updateFrameRate(time) {
    var second = Math.floor(time / 1000); // ms to integer seconds
    if (second != currentSecond) {
       frameRate = frameCount;
       frameCount = 0;
       currentSecond = second;
    }
    frameCount ++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to test this out later.

Comment: This worked great, but it's not completely accurate if I want to display the framerate somewhere, as the number increases constantly.

Comment: What I mean is that, I was looking for "what is the framerate in the last 1 second?" or current framerate.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to reset frameCount for the new second

Answer (score 0):

The proposed structure seems to be:

```
  var numFrames = 0;
  var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(
      function(frame) {

        //game logic
           //move ball
           //check collisions - if collision occurs, stop animation
           //redraw 
        numFrames++;
      }
  }

  setInterval(function(){
     alert(numFrames/1000);  //number of frames per second
     numFrames = 0;  //reset frame count
  },1000);   //every second
```

would this be the case?

Comment: wait, would I be dividing by 1000 in the alert? Basically, divide by ms or sec?

Comment: don't alert once per second; in any case, I believe JS timestamps are in milliseconds since the epoch