# Difference in number of frame rates on different browsers

Tags: kineticjs

Suddenly, a simple animation has a different frameRate in chrome (approx 30fps) and firefox (approx 7fps).
Is that a right behavior ? And could i adjust framRate in my animation function ?

Comment: How you draw your code? Do you use `requestAnimationFrame()`? (Also, FPS always depends on the browser's speed and the quality of your code)

Comment: How are you checking the fps?

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
// variables accessible from within function(frame)
var frameCount = 0;
var currentSecond = 0;
var frameRate = 0;

// within function(frame), called with current time on each new frame
function updateFrameRate(time) {
    var second = Math.floor(time / 1000); // ms to integer seconds
    if (second != currentSecond) {
       frameRate = frameCount;
       frameCount = 0;
       currentSecond = second;
    }
    frameCount ++;
}
```

A simple implementation, with "frames in a 1s interval". You can smoothen it out using, say, frames in a 5s interval

you can find more here [Animation, FPS, and KineticJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403875/animation-fps-and-kineticjs)

Comment: Please see this thread on copy pasting answers from another question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions

Comment: I mean, how can i set both 30 fps to chrome and firefox directly.